# Why is XCode recommending a higher deployment target than necessary?

Tags: ios, xcode

My project has a deployment target of iOS 11.0 or higher.

[image]

But why is Xcode 12 recommending to change the minimum deployment target to 12? This is a really bad advise because I would be reducing the number of users that could install the app. Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: Happening to me too, I have my DT set to 11.0 and it is saying it is a "Validate Project Settings" warning to not have it at 12.0.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug. XCode 12 seems also to have problems with long StringAttributes. It fails compiling them.  They rushed it for no reason. iPhone 12 didn't even get released at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Apple always tried to push every user to use the newest version of everything. You can see this for example in the annoying badges everywhere that you cannot get rid of (talking about OS updates).

This is just the next logical step. By making you use only the newest OS version (to be precise: `n-2` - but most developers will then choose `n` anyway) they make sure your users have to update to a newer OS version if they want to keep using your app.

As long as you don't need newer OS version for certain features there is no reason to update.